# git diff --numstat by strings instead of file paths

Tags: linux, bash, git, diff, git-diff

I'm trying to run `git diff --no-index --numstat <string> <string>` on Linux (Debian Docker container), but I'm failing in finding a way to achieve this. In essence I want to pass the files' contents as strings instead of their file paths. The goal is to retrieve the stats from the `--numstat` flag.

This command should be executable outside of a `git` repository/directory and on Linux. So far, I've found two solutions which lack the former requirements:

1. `git diff --no-index --numstat /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 3<<<$(echo "<string>") 4<<<$(echo "<string>")`: This works on MacOS, but fails to work on Linux.
2. `git diff --numstat $(echo <string> | git hash-object -w --stdin) $(echo <string> | git hash-object -w --stdin)`: which only works inside `git` repositories (got this partial solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853613/is-it-possible-to-git-diff-2-strings))

Certainly there must be a way to achieve this, either via some `git` command or other `bash` concepts I'm unaware of. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to use `git` as diff-tool? If so, you could just use `diff`or `diffstat`under Linux, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767198/how-to-get-diff-to-report-summary-of-new-changed-and-deleted-lines

Answer (score 2):

The reason that solution 1. isn't working is that `/dev/fd/3` and `/dev/fd/4` are symlinks and `git diff` does not follow symlinks but instead uses their link target string as their "content".

The only way to pass a string to `git diff` directly instead of a file is as stdin - which obviously only works for one of the files. So I see only two possible solutions to your problem:

1. write the strings to (temporary) files first, then pass them to `git diff`
2. use another tool, as suggested by [@B--rian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8330162/b-rian) in the comment

---

Another, shorter version of 1. using [process substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) would be:

```sh
git diff --no-index --numstat <(echo "<string1>") <(echo "<string2>")
```

Which unfortunately doesn't work either for the same reason/because `git diff` does not support process substitution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49636553/11932806